# Keep active session in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

A query I am new to the ionic 3 framework and I would like you to help me how to keep the session started, because every time I close the application I have to log in again, I thank you very much if you help me solve this problem, below I will be Sharing my code.

```
 login(){
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: "Cargando..",
          duration: 10000
        });  
        loader.present();
    if(this.userData.email != "" && this.userData.password != ""){
     this.authService.postData(this.userData, "login").then((result) =>{
      loader.dismiss();
     this.resposeData = result;
     if(this.resposeData.userData){
           window.localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.resposeData) );
            if (window.localStorage.getItem('userData') != null) {
               console.log(this.resposeData.userData );
              this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          } else {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
          }
        }else if(this.resposeData.error){
          this.showalertinfo();
        } 
     }, (err) => {
     loader.dismiss();
      this.showalertinfo();
       //Connection failed message
     });
    }
    else{
     loader.dismiss();
     this.showalertinfo();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You dont need to login each time after each time you close the application. Please find the below steps

1. Once you login your application for the first time, store the user details in `localStorage`.
   `localStorage.setItem('userDetails',user-details)`
2. Once you restart your application in `app.component.ts` validate user like,

   `let userExists = localStorage.getItem('userDetails');`

   `if(userExists){
          Set HomePage as Root
    }else{
          Set Login Page as Root
    }`
3. The last step is in `onInit()` of `HomePage` you can take the user detials from `localStorage`. Or in the previous step pass the user details along with `navCtrl`. In `ngOnInit()` fetch the details using `navParams`